# Turning a (4D matrix * 1D vector) operation into independent (3D matrix * 0D scalar) operations without loops

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

Is there any way to vectorize the following:

```
    for i = 1:6
        te = k(:,:,:,i).*(c(i));
    end
```

I'm trying to multiply a 4D matrix, k, by a vector, c, by breaking it up into independent (3D matrix * scalar) operations. I already have two other unavoidable for loops within a while loop in this function file, and am trying my best to avoid loops.

Any insight on this will be much appreciated!

-SC

Comment: A for loop is probably your best option for anything more than 2D matrix.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Tried playing around with matrix indexing; e.g. `k([3, 3; 3 3])` to see what'd happen, but got super confused. Unsure if it's the right alley to go down anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using [MTIMESX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support) - a Fast matrix multiplication tool with multidimensional support  by James Tursa, found in Matlab's file exchange.

It is as simple as:

```
C = mtimesx(A,B)
```

performs the calculation C = A * B

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this is a case for bsxfun:

```
te=bsxfun(@times, k, permute(c,[3 4 1 2])); % c is a row vector
```

Or

```
te=bsxfun(@times, k, permute(c,[3 4 2 1])); % c is a column vector
```

This is assuming that the 4th dimension of k has the same size as c. If not, then you can use submatrix indexing:

```
te=bsxfun(@times, k(:,:,:,1:length(c)), permute(c,[3 4 2 1])); % c is a column vector
```

Comment: +1 for the effort although the reality is that removing a for loop and replacing it with a one line code is not always faster that the original. For example your code takes 75% longer to run than the original for loop code.

Comment: For 10000 tests on a 10x10x10x10 and 10x10x10x5000 matrix, the bsxfun runs about 10% slower than the for loop. Agreed it is not faster, but I do disagree on the magnitude ;)